# switch off scientific notation in Gson double serialization

Tags: java, json, format, double, gson

When I use Gson to serialize an Object that contains a double value close to zero it is using the scientific E-notation:

```
{"doublevaule":5.6E-4}
```

How do I tell Gson to generate

```
{"doublevaule":0.00056}
```

instead? I can implement a custom JsonSerializer, but it returns a JsonElement. I would have to return a JsonPrimitive containing a double having no control about how that is serialized.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is that a problem? Scientific notation is valid in JSON and anything handling JSON should be able to parse that correctly (to exactly the same value as if scientific notation were not used).

Comment: I don't argue with that, you are right Joachim. Still I would like my JSON to not contain scientific notations. Is that doable with GSon?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, simply due to the fact I have a broken JSON consumer that can't handle exponents. I realise the *real* fix is to sort the consumer, but sometimes that's out of our control. Hence I think this is a reasonable (if unusual) requirement

Answer (score 14):

Why not provide a new serialiser for `Double` ? (You will likely have to rewrite your object to use `Double` instead of `double`).

Then in the serialiser you can convert to a `BigDecimal`, and play with the scale etc.

e.g.

```
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Double.class,  new JsonSerializer<Double>() {
        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(final Double src, final Type typeOfSrc, final JsonSerializationContext context) {
            BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.valueOf(src);

            return new JsonPrimitive(value);
        }
    });

    gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

The above will render (say) `9.166666E-6` as `0.000009166666`

Comment: With Kotlin - see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57254418/2826184

Comment: I tried gson.toJson("{\"doublevaule\":5.6E-4}"); after above lines of code, I am still getting the value as it. i.e., out put of above line is 5.6E-4

Answer (score 5):

A minor change on [Brian Agnew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18892735/):

```
public class DoubleJsonSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Double> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(final Double src, final Type typeOfSrc, final JsonSerializationContext context) {
        BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.valueOf(src);
        try {
            value = new BigDecimal(value.toBigIntegerExact());
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            // ignore
        }

        return new JsonPrimitive(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Internally GSON uses Number#toString so we just need to create a new instance of a Number:

```
.registerTypeAdapter(Double.class, new JsonSerializer<Double>() {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(final Double src, final Type typeOfSrc, final JsonSerializationContext context) {

        Number n = new Number() {

            @Override
            public long longValue() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public int intValue() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public float floatValue() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public double doubleValue() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return new BigDecimal(src).toPlainString();
            }

        };

        return new JsonPrimitive(n);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try extending [`JsonWriter`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html) and overriding [the method `value(double)`](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.java#445)

It doesn't seem to be built to be modified like this (you'll pretty much need to duplicate the existing code), but it should be possible to get it working.

Unfortunately I see no other reason to influence the output format.

Comment: This is the right approach, but it will probably require a lot of duplicated code. JsonWriter wasn't designed for this kind of extensibility and lacks the necessary hooks.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom serializer for `Double`

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Double.class,  new JsonSerializer<Double>() {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Double originalValue, Type typeOf, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        BigDecimal bigValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(originalValue);

        return new JsonPrimitive(bigValue.toPlainString());
    }
});
```

Before: {"Amount": 1.0E9}

After: {"Amount": "1000000000"}

Not exactly perfect since it's a String in the JSON.

Answer (score 2):

With Kotlin:

```
    val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(object: TypeToken<Double>() {}.type, object : JsonSerializer<Double> {
        override fun serialize(src: Double, typeOfSrc: Type, context: JsonSerializationContext): JsonElement {
            val value = BigDecimal.valueOf(src)
            return JsonPrimitive(value)
        }
    })

    val gson = gsonBuilder.create()
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I can't get the solution with BigDecimal to work as suggested here by many people. So I had to write it like that:

```
.registerTypeAdapter(object : TypeToken<Double>() {}.type, object : JsonSerializer<Double> {
    override fun serialize(src: Double, typeOfSrc: Type, context: JsonSerializationContext): JsonElement =
        JsonPrimitive(src.toBigDecimal().toPlainString().toBigDecimal())
})
```