# How to avoid exponentional/scientific notation in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, double, exponential, scientific-notation

In one of my projects, when i calculate the grand total

```
  shippingDetails.grandTotal = 3.448873577E7
```

instead of `34488749.7‬`
where `grandTotal` is of type `Double`

The above object is in my data class and i need to pass as request body for a request, but it fails since it's having scientific notation.

```
@POST(AppConstants.Network.CONFIRM_PENDING_SHIPPING)
fun confirmPendingShipping(
    @Header("Authorization") token: String,
    @Body shippingItems: RequestConfirmShipping
): Single<ResponsePendingShipping>
```

I'm passing it as body of post using `Retrofit`

Comment: which type is the variable, and how exactly are you passing it as request body

Comment: Please add the error as well.

Comment: in general, `E7` should be accepted by the server, if it expects double value. It is legit double. But if the server is implemented incorrectly, and you can do nothing about it, you may try to format the number as the string

Comment: What's the converter you're using with retrofit and how it is configured?

Comment: `addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` @laalto

Comment: The API is broken if it doesn't allow scientific notation in JSON numbers but anyway you can configure it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119094/switch-off-scientific-notation-in-gson-double-serialization