# Request in Retrofit returns inappropriate data

Tags: android, types, type-conversion

My problem is that I make a request in Android application which should return BigDecimal, instead, I got 2.0E7 value. I tried make this request in Postman and it returns 20000000 (proper value). I changed type of value in my data class to BigDecimal and to String and in both cases I got 2.0E7. I need to get the proper value. Can someone help in solving this issue?

Comment: are you using gson converter ?

Comment: Yes I am using gson converter

Comment: Gson has this problem see https://github.com/google/gson/issues/968 . There are some work arounds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119094/switch-off-scientific-notation-in-gson-double-serialization) . Use jackson or moshi converters instead of gson

Answer (score 0):

You can use Long type for that (20000000).

In my project I am getting below json and I used long type in my model class

JSON

```
{
    "success": {
        "value": 20000000
    }
}
```

Models class

```
public class Success {

    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    private Long value;

    public Long getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Long value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this same question [How to prevent Gson from converting a long number (a json string ) to scientific notation format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586299/how-to-prevent-gson-from-converting-a-long-number-a-json-string-to-scientific)

This May help you...

Comment: I used String, but it still returns 2.0E7

Comment: I have the same problem previously and its been resolved by just changing its type to string type.